# The show_letters function should print out each letter of a word on a separate line. Fill in the blanks to make that happen

Tags: python

Should print one line per letter

```py
def show_letters(word):
    for __:
        print(__)

show_letters("Hello")
# Should print one line per letter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
def show_letters(word):
  for x in range(0, len(word)):
    print(word[x])

show_letters("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Try this out:

```
# Function to print each letter in a word
def show_letters(word):
    # Iterate over each letter in the word
    for letter in word:
        # Print each letter on a new line
        print(letter)

show_letters("Hello")
```